# Is it correct to use “with” in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> The purchase is made **with** payment deferred until March.

> The hospital accepted to buy the medical equipments **with** payment that will be made end of next month.

> The company won’t sell their products **with** payment terms of 90 days because of the financial need.

In these sentences, I try to say that a purchase will be made but payment will be made latet. In this case is it grammaticaly correct to use the preposition “with” ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the answer to this sort of question, it depends on the specific words, as words (nouns, verbs, adjectives) in English often require specific prepositions or constructions, and different words may have different requirements even if their meaning is the same.

I find the first example "The purchase is made with payment deferred until March" completely natural.

I find "with" works in the second example, but it needs some adjustment. If you change it to

> The hospital agreed to buy the medical equipments with payment **to be** made end of next month.

I can't completely explain why I make this change, but it is more idiomatic this way. I think it is that in your sentence the complement of "with" is the payment, with an incidental relative clause applying to the payment - but that incidental relative clause is actually the important information. In my modified version "payment to be made end of next month" is a single item, a to-infinitive clause with a subject, and so the whole of it expresses the condition that "with" introduces.

Note that I have also changed "accepted" to "agreed": "accept" does not take a to-infinitive clause as its complement.

Your third sentence "The company won’t sell their products with payment terms of 90 days because of the financial need" is fine as regards the "with" phrase.

"Because of the financial need" doesn't work, but that is a different issue. I'm not sure what to suggest about that, because I'm not sure exactly what it is intended to mean. "Because of financial need" is possible, but we don't usually use "need" in that way. Perhaps "because of financial constraints", or "because of financial pressures", or "because of the financial situation".